# R import txt/csv file with separator inside quotes

Tags: r, csv, txt

I try to import a txt/csv file with R, and here is a simplified example:

```
txt <- "
id,value
001,'Mary'
002,'Mary's, husband'"
```

For the second line, I would like to consider the value of the variable `value` as `Mary's, husband` delimited with `'` and there is also `'` after `Mary`.

We can use ignore the quotes and clean after importing. But since `,` is also the separator, there is a bug when importing as follows:

```
df1 <- read.csv(textConnection(txt))
df1$value <- gsub("^'|'$", "", df1$value)
df1
```

My question is how to import the data correctly in this case, to have `Mary's, husband` as a single value.

[Update]: as one comment points out, this file is not correctly buit. But we can consider that there are always two columns, and the first `,` is the separator for one row.

Comment: df <- read.csv(text = txt, quote = "'")

Comment: Thank you danh, I update my question. I forgot the situation is a little more complicated.

Comment: Well, the problem is that's an invalid CSV file. If you have quotes in quotes those should be escaped. Where did this CSV file come from? It would be better to fix the mistake at the time the file is made rather than clean up the mess later.

Comment: Using `read_csv`  from the tidyverse will handle this automatically, but it will remove the "'" inside of Mary's, if that is acceptable:  `df <- read_csv(txt, quote = "'")`